# Message poping up while installing python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

The message popping up while installing python packages. What should I do?

```
 The script tqdm.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python36\Scripts' which 
is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this 
warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `c:\program files\python36\Scripts` to your Windows environment PATH variable.

You can do this by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (opens up the run command window) and executing `sysdm.cpl`. The adavanced system settings window pops up where you then click on the **Advanced** tab and hit the button labeled **Environment variables**.
Now you have two sections in front of you: the *user variables* and the *system variables*. I'd almost always advise you to only make changes in your user variables so you won't change any system or other users' settings. If you don't already have a **PATH** variable in your *user variables* section, create one by clicking *New*. Else edit the existing one by hitting *Edit* and change it to

```
c:\program files\python36\Scripts;%PATH%;<whatever else was here>
```

Comment: Was this helpful?